# Enable sound routing from input to output on same sound card with Fedora

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio

I want to plug in my phone with an audio cable into the audio input jack in my computer and have it play on the speakers also connected to my computer. Both input and output are built in to the motherboard. I'm running Fedora 26 with Gnome and the pulseaudio audio system. I opened the audio properties/settings and selected the input and could see the visualizer show my music, and I could test the speakers which worked, but how do I route the input to the speakers?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following command to work:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback
```